# Use VBA to find all cells in a range with a solitary EM dash and delete those cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched for ages but found no easy way to do this.

I have a table with negative and positive numbers and a good number of cells with a solitary Em dash (or equivalent), as in characters that look like dashes.

I want to select a range and delete all such cells.

I thought to use Len(<2) but still can not find an easy way to use VBA to do it.

Hi to replace some types of dash i used the code below. But i could not figure out how to only choose cells with a solitary dash. Choosing a length of one will find cells but it might not be a perfect way to searh.

```
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B1:K" & LastRow).Select
Cells.Replace What:=ChrW(8722), Replacement:=Chr(45), lookat:=xlPart
Cells.Replace What:=Chr(150), Replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart
End Sub
```

Thanks

Neil

Comment: What does "(or equivalent)" mean? Do the cells contain a dash, or zero formatted as a dash? In any case, SO is not meant to be a code-writing service, so can you [edit] your question with what you have tried?

Answer (score -1):

```
    Sub RemoveDashes()
     Dim m, r, cell As Object
     Dim b As Boolean

     Set m = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
     Do
      Set m = m.Offset(1, 0)
      Set r = m.Resize(25, 1)
      b = False
      For Each cell In r
       If cell.Value <> "" Then
        b = True
       End If
      Next cell

'covers em, en, and hyphen:
      If m.Value = "—" Or m.Value = "–" Or m.Value = "-" Then m.Value = ""
     Loop Until b = False
    End Sub
```